# Makefile rules that behave differently with -s (or --silent) mode

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a large project I'm working on, there are rules that look something like the following:

```
output: input
    echo Building $@; command_to_build output
```

I think that the author of the Makefile generally builds with make -s, in which case this sort of makes sense (although it does stop you cut/pasting stuff from the console).

Is there a way to get make to echo the equivalent of "Building $@" when run in silent mode but to just print out the actual build command when running normally?

The half-way house I came up with is

```
output: input
    @echo Building $@
    command_to_build output
```

which is marginally better than before (and looks the same with -s), but still spams "Building foo" messages to the console if you're not using -s.

In case it's relevant, this source tree only ever gets compiled with GNU Make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, but it's a bit roundabout. The trick is to use the special variable `MAKEFLAGS` (which I believe is GNU-specific).

`MAKEFLAGS` contains the flags passed to make in a fairly parseable format; options that have a single-character form are grouped in its first word if any are passed, and if none were passed, `MAKEFLAGS` either begins with a `-` or is empty. That is to say:

- `make -ks` yields `MAKEFLAGS = ks`
- `make -j2 --silent` yields `MAKEFLAGS = s -j --jobserver-fds=3,4`
- `make --warn-undefined-variables` yields `MAKEFLAGS = --warn-undefined-variables`

an so forth. So we can use this:

```
ifneq (,$(filter-out -%,$(word 1,$(MAKEFLAGS))))
  SILENT = $(findstring s,$(word 1,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
else
  SILENT =
endif
```

`SILENT` will be `s` if any of `-s`, `--silent` or `--quiet` are passed (or any other option that may be introduced in the future whose single-character equivalent is `-s`) and empty otherwise. This can later be used like so:

```
ifeq (s,$(SILENT))
  echo Building $@
endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not sure the filter is quite correct (it didn't work here, because `MAKEFLAGS` looked like `s` or `ks` etc.) However, testing for `$(findstring s,$(MAKEFLAGS))` instead seems to work fine (the "Conditionals that Test Flags" section of the Make manual has a similar example).

Comment: Hum. Works for me, with GNU make 4.0. The filter is necessary to avoid finding a silent flag when make is called with only a long argument that contains an `s`, e.g. `make --warn-undefined-variables`; it should give the first word in `MAKEFLAGS` unless that word begins with a `-`. How did you call make when it failed?

Comment: Oh, there was a typo in the answer -- I forgot `$()` in the `filter` command. Fixed that, it's probably why it broke for you. I wonder why it worked for me, though.

Comment: Now I understand. Shouldn't it be `filter-out` then? I think you want to throw away things starting with a hyphen?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Silly copypasta mistake; my bad.